# Javascript Geomap?

Tags: map

Are there any javascript geomaps like this one (which is in flash)? http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

check out http://mapbox.com/, http://www.webglearth.com/, http://www.chromeexperiments.com/globe

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be anything on code.google.com for a javascript based Visualization Geomap. The flash version is the only one.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps JavaScript API makes it possible to develop a solution like this in JavaScript.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html